# Deploying a project with a SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am trying to deploy an application that uses a `.SDF` file and the Entity Framework. Whenever the deployed application tries to use the entity (connect to the DB) I get the error:

> The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.
>   System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
>   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
>   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)

My connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="DBEntities" 
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/DB_Model.csdl|res://*/DB_Model.ssdl|res://*/DB_Model.msl;
    provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;
    provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\DB.sdf&quot;" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have read somewhere that I may need to have a reference to the dll for `System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5` but I am unsure. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either install the 3.5 SP2 runtime on the target system, or use Private Deployment as described here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/05/private-deployment-of-sql-server.html

Answer (score 0):

- Under your project properties, on the **Publish** tab, click **Application Files**.
- Look for **System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll** (possibly by checking the **Show All Files** box).
- Make sure that its **Publish Status** is **Include**.